# Do I need to wrap further waitFor() steps in then()?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

As far as I know `open()` and `waitFor()` require following steps to be wrapped in `then()`:

```
casper.click(x('//button[text()="Login"]'));

casper.waitForSelector(x('//span[text()="Navigation"]]'));

casper.capture('1.png');

casper.then(function () {
  casper.capture('2.png'); // Only this shows the navigation
});
```

When I have multiple `waitFor()` steps, do I need to chain them myself or do they chain themselves?

```
casper.click(x('//button[text()="Login"]'));
casper.waitForSelector(x('//span[text()="Navigation"]]'));
casper.waitWhileSelector(x('//span[text()="Loading"]]'));
casper.then(function () {
  casper.capture('1.png'); // Under which condition will this be executed?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `casper.wait*` functions are steps in the same way that `casper.then` is. So they don't need to be wrapped in `then`. If you do this, keep in mind, that the internal step of `wait*` will be added to the queue after all the other steps in a higher (hierarchically) level.

The second code executes the same as it is depicted. The `wait*` function do wait.